# HTML 5 video won't play in IE10 - "Invalid Source"

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video

I've got this code:

```
<video width="365" height="250" controls>
   <source src="../videos/MiSIPP_Overview.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="../videos/MiSIPP_Overview_OGV.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
   (HTML 5 video player has failed)
</video>
```

It works correctly in Chrome and also in Firefox (using the OGG fall-back), but it resolutely *won't* work in IE10, or emulated IE9.  I get "Invalid Source".

I've tried changing the src tag to point to the hosted file via http... but that doesn't work either.

I've also tried using Freemake Video Converter to generate a .webm file, and pointing to that instead.  Still no dice.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: what doctype are you using?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem and found that the video codec was not supported. Get a video converter software (like Oxelon - it is free) and choose the output to be .mp4 (even the source is .mp4). And choose the video codec to be (H264), and the audio codec to be (AAC). This will solve your problem.

Omar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are doing the IE9 emulation, but try this in the head section if you have not done so already.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the

```
<source src="../videos/MiSIPP_Overview_OGV.webm" type="video/webm" />
```

source type in code. its supports in IE browser.